# Salesforce Missing Headers Puzzle

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am trying to access Salesforce headers from a visualforce as well as inline Visualforce page. Both the headers are different. My Objective was to get the Ip address from within Visualforce page. I was able to get it from a VF page while not in inline VF Page - What could be missing. Pasting both the headers below for reference:

Header as in independent VF Page:

{Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8, Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, sdch, Accept-Language=en-US,en;q=0.8, Cache-Control=max-stale=0, CipherSuite=AES256-SHA TLSv1.2 256-bits, Connection=keep-alive, Host=maseratispaceq.ap1.visual.force.com, Referer=https://maseratispaceq.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/IPAddress, User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36, X-BlueCoat-Via=02e34aac1d4420b1, X-Salesforce-Forwarded-To=ap1.salesforce.com, X-Salesforce-SIP=65.116.212.3}

Header as in Inline VF Page:

{CipherSuite=AES256-SHA TLSv1 256-bits, core.apexpages.framework.ApexViewServlet.getContentReflectError=true, core.apexpages.framework.ApexViewServlet.getContentRequest=1, Host=maseratispaceq.ap1.visual.force.com, User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36, X-Salesforce-PDF=AAAAAUwj_BRwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwpYz60xaIbnbiOgFCj3usFFqT128Tl0j8v43lSJCEqURiv38yxmjs5saKfPvaLHg4wBP_AhxJWr6dMq4BJTe4Oo=}

Comment: Are you referring to the `X-Salesforce-SIP` header? Why do you need access to this IP address? Also, is the inline Visualforce page being rendered as a PDF?

Comment: Yes - I am referring to the X-Salesforce-SIP. I am taking this IP to restrict users for that particular VF page. No the inline page is not a pdf - that is what confusing me why X-Salesforce-pdf in header

Comment: Can you not use one of the built in mechanisms to control access to Visualforce pages? [Visualforce Page Security Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=pages_page_level_security.htm&language=en_US)
Why are you trying to restrict access by IP address?

Comment: Yes - could do that. But just wanted to see the ip so printed in a inline VF page and i was not able to get that. Thats what made me to wonder why the headers are different in both the cases.